# How to get MJPG stream video from android IPWebcam using opencv

Tags: android, c++, opencv, video-streaming

I am using the IP Webcam program on android and receiving it on my PC by WiFi. What I want is to use opencv in Visual Studio, C++, to get that video stream, there is an option to get MJPG stream by the following URL: http://MyIP:port/videofeed
How to get it using opencv?

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but I hope this can help someone (same as [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15487578/2023516))

> OpenCV expects a filename extension for its VideoCapture argument,
>   even though one isn't always necessary (like in your case).
>
> You can "trick" it by passing in a dummy parameter which ends in the
>   `mjpg` extension:

So perhaps try:

```
VideoCapture vc;
ipCam.open("http://MyIP:port/videofeed/?dummy=param.mjpg")
```

Comment: This actually works, but without the extra '/' after videofeed. 
CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromFile("http://IP:port/videofeed?dummy=param.mjpg");
Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Install [IP Camera Adapter](http://ip-webcam.appspot.com/) and configure it to capture the videostream. Then install [ManyCam](http://manycam.com/) and you'll see "MPEG Camera" in the camera section.(you'll see the same instructions if you go to the link on how to setup IPWebCam for skype)
Now you can access your MJPG stream just like a webcam through openCV. I tried this with OpenCV 2.2 + QT and works well.
Think this helps.

Comment: Interesting solution but it would be nice to see a similar solution for linux.

Answer (score 1):

I did a dirty patch to make openCV working with android ipWebcam:

In the file OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp

In the function bool CvCapture_FFMPEG::open( const char* _filename )

replace:

```
int err = av_open_input_file(&ic, _filename, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

by

```
AVInputFormat* iformat = av_find_input_format("mjpeg");
int err = av_open_input_file(&ic, _filename, iformat, 0, NULL);
ic->iformat = iformat;
```

and comment:

```
err = av_seek_frame(ic, video_stream, 10, 0);
if (err < 0)
{
    filename=(char*)malloc(strlen(_filename)+1);
    strcpy(filename, _filename);
    // reopen videofile to 'seek' back to first frame
    reopen();
}
else
{
    // seek seems to work, so we don't need the filename,
    // but we still need to seek back to filestart
    filename=NULL;
    int64_t ts    = video_st->first_dts;
    int     flags = AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME | AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD;
    av_seek_frame(ic, video_stream, ts, flags);
}
```

That should work. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution (im using IP Webcam on android):

```
CvCapture* capture = 0;
capture = cvCaptureFromFile("http://IP:Port/videofeed?dummy=param.mjpg");
```

I am not able to comment, so im posting new post. In original answer is an error - used / before dummy. THX for solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's an old question, so may be a while before anyone can confirm your improved answer. You will be able to comment on other posts when your account has enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Working example for me

```
// OpenCVTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

/**
* @function main
*/
int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    CvCapture* capture;
    IplImage* frame = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        //Read the video stream
        capture = cvCaptureFromFile("http://192.168.1.129:8080/webcam.mjpeg");
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

        // create a window to display detected faces
        cvNamedWindow("Sample Program", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

        // display face detections
        cvShowImage("Sample Program", frame);

        int c = cvWaitKey(10);
        if( (char)c == 27 ) { exit(0); }

    }

    // clean up and release resources
    cvReleaseImage(&frame);

    return 0;

}
```

Broadcast mjpeg from a webcam with vlc, how described at http://tumblr.martinml.com/post/2108887785/how-to-broadcast-a-mjpeg-stream-from-your-webcam-with