# Read stream from specific link

Tags: opencv, mjpeg

I need to read stream from mjpeg with OpenCV library. In more details, I need to read `http://194.126.108.66:8887/`. But when I try to do it with

```
VideoCapture ipCam;
ipCam.open("http://194.126.108.66:8887/")
```

I get the error `icvOpenAvi_XINE(): Unable to initialize video driver`.

I have tested this code with another link to mjpeg - http://c-cam.uchicago.edu/mjpg/video.mjpg
It works fine.
What is the difference between these 2 links? And how to read `http://194.126.108.66:8887/`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV with Network Cameras](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712998/opencv-with-network-cameras)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV expects a filename extension for its VideoCapture argument, even though one isn't always necessary (like in your case).

You can "trick" it by passing in a dummy parameter which ends in the mjpg extension:

```
ipCam.open("http://194.126.108.66:8887/?dummy=param.mjpg")
```

This worked in my similar OpenCV Python case, so good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is worked for me with Mjpeg streamer and OpenCV

```
cap.open("http://192.168.1.206:8080/?action=stream?dummy=param.mjpg")
```