# MJPEG stream fails to open in OpenCV 2.4

Tags: c++, opencv, mjpeg

I am having an issue getting OpenCV 2.4 to capture from an MJPEG stream from a Raspberry Pi, I have checked the stream URL in a browser and it seems to be working fine, however when I try to open it in OpenCV it seems to hang when I attempt to open it (I get neither the error or success messages on the terminal).

```
cv::VideoCapture vcap;
cv::Mat raw_image;

const string videoStreamAddress = "http://192.168.0.28:8080/?action=stream";

if(!vcap.open(videoStreamAddress))
{
    cout<<"Error opening video stream"<<endl;
    return -1;
}

cout<<"Stream opened"<<endl;
```

I am using [MJPEG-Streamer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mjpg-streamer/) to provide the  stream.
The same code works fine when capturing form a RTSP video stream.

EDIT: I tried changing the JPEG quality and resolution of the images captured by `raspistill` on the Pi and I now get the message saying the stream failed to open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, it is similar to what Hitesh suggested, I just needed to have a `.` before `mjpg` to make OpenCV think it was a URI to a file.

I found this in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204185/read-stream-from-specific-link/15487578#15487578) answer to a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a dummy param, that hints at the mjpeg content:

```
const string videoStreamAddress = "http://192.168.0.28:8080/?action=stream&amp;type=mjpg";
```

Comment: Didn't seem to help, could still view it in the browser like this but still no luck in OpenCV.

Comment: Got this to work, just needed to make it look like a file extension.